# Angular2 ng2-file-upload single upload and drop zone both together?

Tags: angularjs, angular, file-upload

I'm using [ng2-file-upload](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-file-upload) module for Angular2 and I want to have a drag and drop area and at the same time the posibility to click in that area and select a single file.

In their examples it is separated and there is no example with both together. For example:

```
<div ng2FileDrop
     [ngClass]="{'nv-file-over': hasBaseDropZoneOver}"
     (fileOver)="fileOverBase($event)"
     [uploader]="uploader"
     class="well my-drop-zone">
     Base drop zone
</div>

Single
<input type="file" ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" />
```

Thanks!

Comment: is it ng2FileDrop working? if it is working can u create plunker for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a solution :)

```
<div class="col-md-6 p_0"
   [ngClass]="{'file-over': hasBaseDropZoneOver}"
   ng2FileDrop [uploader]="uploader"
   (click)="fileInput.click()">

   Base drop zone
   <input type="file" #fileInput ng2FileSelect [uploader]="uploader" style="display: none"/>
</div>
```

Comment: is it ng2FileDrop working? if it is working can u create plunker for this?

Comment: However nothing happens if you drop the file, you just change the CSS class on file over...